# ¿Cómo hacer las validaciones con un botón diferente al submit en asp.net mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Lo que estoy tratando de implementar es un simple botón en un formulario que se encargue de validar las validaciones especificadas en el modelo así como lo hace el botón submit, con la diferencia que este no va al post. Gracias de antemano

Comment: si lo que quieres es validar sin tener que ir al post te recomiendo que te documentes acerca de [Remote] que es otro atributo de validación de asp.net pero esta véz del lado del cliente utilizando json, incluso no tienes ni que dar clic en el botón, va validando en tiempo real

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código de ese intento que estás realizando por favor? Saludos

Comment: definies los atributos de validacion del model? o sea utilizas Data Annotation, porque entiendo puedes habilitar las validaciones